# API Testing with Postman to Load Balancer

Tags: api, postman, load-balancing

I am using Postman to do API testing. We have multiple API Gateways which is load balanced using round robin. But when executing APIs using the Postman, I found that it always served by the same API Gateway until status code returned is not 200. (e.g. 401). I use the netstat to check the TCP connections and found that Postman always use the same TCP connection for every successful calls. Is there any setting to change this behavior?

When I use curl and don't experience the same which load balancing between nodes correctly.

Thanks!

Bryan

Comment: Try using SoapUI as I've found Postman to be a very basic RESTful app to test endpoints...